# how to save small chunks of an image into my sd card in Android

Tags: android

First, I am sorry for my poor English

I am working on a project that asks the user to select an image from a gallery. After the user has selected the image, the image will be immediately divided into 9 small parts as shown in the picture below, I  have done this with the help [with this link](http://androidattop.blogspot.my/2012/05/splitting-image-into-smaller-chunks-in.html?showComment=1401863710401). Now all the chunks are in the ArrayList of Bitmap but I am not able to save them into a database

Question: 
1. how can I select only 6 chunks from the divided picture and save them into a database 
2. how can i retrieve the selected chunks from the database.

[This is the image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4T3R.png)

Comment: What can't you save into the database? If you can save one BLOB in a database, you can save many BLOB's

Comment: `divided into 9 small parts as shown in the picture below`. Thank you. I always wanted to know how many was 9. But now i finally know. Great!